# Locale data in a library

Tags: java, android

I'll better explain the problem with an example: Lets suppose I'm creating a library (.jar) where one of the methods is:

```
String getInternetStatus();
```

It should return a language localized String describing the status of the internet connection but if I use the Context given by the application for retrieve the String it will fail right?

Is possible to define locale Strings in the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store localized strings in a library. Just create a strings.xml file in the appropriate directory in your library - res/values for your default locale, or res/values-de if for example you wanted to provide German versions of your strings. 
Your getInternetStatus() method can then be changed to provide a status variable - boolean for just up/down, or an int to represent a range of values. Then use a case statement to decide which string you are going to display to the user. Getting the localized string at this point looks something like this:

context.getResources().getString(R.string.summary)

Anthony Nolan

Comment: Thx for your answer. And if both the application and the library have R.string.summary in strings.xml?

Comment: Hi, I have not tested that scenario. I would imagine that the value from the app would take precedence over that in the library, but I am not sure. The approach I have taken is to have a strings.xml for the few languages that I normally localize to in my standard library project. This contains strings like Cancel, Delete etc. along with those that are used by any library classes that I have. I can then just refer to these in my layouts or classes and not worry about having to constantly redefine them on each project. I just have to translate the stuff that is unique to that app.